# Parsing strings in Java to replace markers with specific data

Tags: java, string-parsing

I have a bunch of strings which contain some specific markers that should be replaced with images. So at first I created hash map with markers and images:

```
Map<String, String> images = new HashMap<String, String>();
images.put(":img:howdy:", "path/images/hello.png");
images.put(":img:code:", "path/images/code.png");
images.put(":img:smile:", "path/images/sm.png");
//...and 70 more records
```

Strings look like:

> This is a string :img:howdy:, you know it :img:smile:
>
> And even more:img:smile:
>
> This is a string with images:img:code::img:smile:

After parsing all markers are planned to be replaced with images.

I stuck at the following point:

```
Map<String, String> images = new HashMap<String, String>();
images.put(":img:howdy:", "path/images/hello.png");
images.put(":img:code:", "path/images/code.png");
images.put(":img:smile:", "path/images/sm.png");

String[] strings = {"This is a string :img:howdy:, you know it :img:smile:",
                 "And even more:img:smile:",
                 "This is a string with images:img:code::img:smile:"};

for (String text : images.keySet()) {
    for (String string : strings) {
        if(string.contains(text)) {
            string.replace(text, images.get(text));
        }
    }
}
```

Firstly, markers are replaced, but there're to much iterations.
Secondly, if I use, for example, StringBuilder, I have a lot of duplications with some markers replaced and some not.

I'm not strong with string parsing and corresponding algorithms (at the moment), so don't throw stones at me after viewing approach I chose.

**Added**
Reworked a little as Dariusz Waver suggested and here is what I've got:

```
private final String IMAGE_PATTERN = ":s:\\w+:";

//.......

Pattern p = Pattern.compile(IMAGE_PATTERN);
Matcher m = p.matcher(message);
while(m.find())
{
    String imgPattern = message.substring(m.start(), m.end());
    String imgPath = ImgPaths.images.get(imgPattern);
    
    //If there's no such image in Images Map
    if(imgPattern != null) {
        message = message.replace(imgPattern, imgPath);
        m.reset(message);
    }
}

StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
result.append(timestamp).append(" - ").append(sender)
        .append(": ").append(message);
```

Is there any way to make it more optmized taking into account that there's a really huge amount of text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest doing it the other way around: first find all occurences of regex `:\w+:\w+`, then search for it's values in the map, and then, if they are found, replace the strings.

For larger amounts of images and larger amounts of text it will be the better way to do it.

Your code, however, is pretty clean and if you don't have any performance issues you can leave it as it is - provided you actually make the fix posted by jlordo:

```
for (int i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) {
    if(strings[i].contains(text)) {
        strings[i] = strings[i].replace(text, images.get(text));
    }
}
```

Comment: No, he can't leave it as is, see the explanation in my answer.

Comment: @DariuszWawer: No, `string` is a local variable to the inner for loop. Any changes made to it won't be seen in the array.

Comment: seriously, have you never made a mistake like that? if you code in c++ you tend to forget about it; anyway, the answer is fixed, thx jlordo

Comment: Yes, there's a large amount of text (and it constantly changes - resembles chat activity) and approximately 70 images.

Comment: @Dragon then I hope that my idea will help you; if you need some further explaination write it in the comment, I will expand the answer. If you do it yourself you can learn something, so consider attempting doing it:)

Comment: @DariuszWawer, I'll try doing it myself. But if I don't manage to do it, don't you mind I'll ask you to expand the answer then?

Comment: @Dragon not a problem. Good luck!

Comment: @DariuszWawer, updated topic. It works fine, but I don't know whether there's way for more optimization?

Comment: @Dragon I see a problem with running "replace" on a string. You are actually making another search here - and that's a lot of inefficiency. Consider putting the whole message into StringBuilder and then calling sb.replace(start, end, val) based on the matcher.

Comment: @dragon using StringBuilder will also help reducing the number of strings created - because replace edits the same buffer, while string.replace creates a new object each time.

Comment: @DariuszWawer, you mean, I should use StringBuilder in a while loop? There can be only two images per sentence. So I need to parse it twice. But creating String on every loop is filling String Pool that in fact (if I'm not mistaken) can lead to OutOfMemory. So will usage of StringBuilder even for maximum 2 replaces be advantageous in compare to simple String assignment?

Comment: @dragon you have to test it to be sure, but I think it will. You gain a lot using StringBuilder.replace(start, end, string) and you have less objects. You always create a single StringBuilder and at least two strings. So you always gain less objects creation.

Answer (score 1):

`string` is a local variable to your inner for loop. `string.replace()` creates a new string, and doesn't change the current string. But even `string = string.replace(...)` wouldn't help here, because reassigning it won't change the content of the array.

You have to replace your **inner** for loop with:

```
for (int i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) {
    if(strings[i].contains(text)) { // this check is not really necessary
        strings[i] = strings[i].replace(text, images.get(text));
    }
}
```

Comment: Sometimes foreach loop leads to big mistakes. But taking into account that there're a lot of text and images, I think it is memory consumable approach, because on each replacement new string is created and result assignment also leads to creation of a new string in memory (if I'm not mistaken).

Comment: everytime you call `replace()` a new string will be in memory. Doesn't matter if that's within a traditional _for_ loop or a _for each_ loop. Strings are immutable. If you want to remember the new string (the one with the replacement done), you have to assign it to an array index. You can't do that with a _for each_ loop.

Comment: Oh, I meant that I used foreach loop in a place where it is less effective, because data changes. Regarding creation of a new string in memory after each replace() call: Dariusz Wawer put an idea into my head that there can be really huge amount of text and in fact it is :(

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try template libraries like : [StringTemplate](http://www.stringtemplate.org/)?

Sample Code:

```
String[] strings = {"This is a string <howdy>, you know it <smile>",
                     "And even more <smile>",
                     "This is a string with images <code><smile>"};

for (String string : strings) {
    ST hello = new ST(string);

    hello.add("howdy", "path/images/hello.png");
    hello.add("code", "path/images/code.png");
    hello.add("smile", "path/images/sm.png");

    System.out.println(hello.render());
}
```

Why do you want to reinvent the wheel?

Comment: I cannot change markers. And at the end I need to put image inside text. Implementing my own variant I can control such things. But I agree that one should avoid wheel reinvention...until it is a study process :)

Comment: For future reference, StringTemplate allows use of custom markers.

Answer (score 0):

1- `.contains` doesn't seem necessary

2- String being immutable you have to do `String string = string.replaceAll(...)`

Comment: `replace()` also replaces all occurences ;) First paramter is a string literal, not a regex, though. To change the strings in his array, there has to a an assignment like `array[index] = newstring;`.

Comment: Ok, they should review their function name ;)

Comment: `replaceAll()` is already taken ;) Both are well documented, though. The real problem here is not strings beeing immutable, but that he's not changing the content of the array in his nested loop.